# What is the meaning of "html.parser" when doing BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am not getting the BeautifulSoup's syntax, especially the purpose of HTML parser inside the parenthesis.

```
BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the defining which library you want to use for parsing the `source_code`. Checkout the options [in the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) and how they compare.

From what I understand, "html.parser" will use Python3 html module found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).

More reading on parsers:

- [Parser differences demo](https://github.com/wention/BeautifulSoup4/blob/03a2b3a9d1fc5877212d9d382a512663f24c887d/scripts/demonstrate_parser_differences.py)
- [A diagnostics method which shows you which packages are used](https://github.com/wention/BeautifulSoup4/blob/03a2b3a9d1fc5877212d9d382a512663f24c887d/bs4/diagnose.py#L18)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [BeautifulSoup source code](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup) to understand the constructor parameters and how they are used. Here is the code for the BeautifulSoup class [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/__init__.py#L82):

```
def __init__(self, markup="", features=None, builder=None,
             parse_only=None, from_encoding=None, exclude_encodings=None,
             **kwargs):
    ...
    if builder is None:
        original_features = features
        if isinstance(features, basestring):
            features = [features]
        if features is None or len(features) == 0:
            features = self.DEFAULT_BUILDER_FEATURES
        builder_class = builder_registry.lookup(*features)
        if builder_class is None:
            raise FeatureNotFound(
                "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you "
                "requested: %s. Do you need to install a parser library?"
                % ",".join(features))
        builder = builder_class()
        if not (original_features == builder.NAME or
                original_features in builder.ALTERNATE_NAMES):
            if builder.is_xml:
                markup_type = "XML"
            else:
                markup_type = "HTML"
```

The 1st argument is the markup code (ex. HTML code) and the 2nd argument specifies [how to parse that markup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#specifying-the-parser-to-use), with the default being the built-in HTML parser but it can be overriden:

> You can override this by specifying one of the following:
>
> - What type of markup you want to parse. Currently supported are “html”, “xml”, and “html5”.
> - The name of the parser library you want to use. Currently supported options are “lxml”, “html5lib”, and “html.parser” (Python’s built-in HTML parser).